# Scalacache with redis support

Tags: scala, redis, codec

I am trying to integrate redis to scalacache. Keys are usually string but values can be objects, Set[String], etc. Cache is initialized by this

```
val cache: RedisCache = RedisCache(config.host, config.port)
private implicit val scalaCache: ScalaCache[Array[Byte]] = ScalaCache(cacheService.cache)
```

But while calling put, i am getting this error "Could not find any Codecs for type Set[String] and Repr". Looks like i need to provide codec for my cache input as suggested [here](https://github.com/cb372/scalacache#custom-codec) so i added,

```
class A extends Codec[Set[String], Array[Byte]] with GZippingBinaryCodec[Set[String]]
```

Even after, my class A, is throwing the same error. What am i missing.

Comment: Please paste the complete and working code snippet. The variables that you used are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its solved in next release by binary and circe serialization. I am on version 10 and solved by the following,

```
implicit object SetBindaryCodec extends Codec[Any, Array[Byte]] {
    override def serialize(value: Any): Array[Byte] = {
      val stream: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
      val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(stream)
      oos.writeObject(value)
      oos.close()
      stream.toByteArray
    }

    override def deserialize(data: Array[Byte]): Any = {
      val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
      val value = ois.readObject
      ois.close()
      value
    }
  }
```

Perks of being up to date. Will upgrade the version, posted it just in case somebody needs it.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/cb372/scalacache#custom-codec), you can either serialize values in a binary format:

```
import scalacache.serialization.binary._
```

or as JSON using circe:

```
 import scalacache.serialization.circe._
 import io.circe.generic.auto._
```